# How to override template for view mode of a entity within a module?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I see in theme suggestion array that I can override template for my custom entity type based on view mode like this:

> custom_entity__custom_entity__view_mode_name

Now I want to put

> custom-entity--custom-entity--view-mode-name.tpl.php

inside custom module.

I'm trying something like:

```
function custom_module_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {

  if (isset($theme_registry['entity'])) {

    $entity = &$theme_registry['entity'];

    if (!isset($entity['theme paths'])) {
      $entity['theme paths'] = array();
    }

    $entity['theme paths'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module') . '/templates';

    if (isset($entity['theme path'])) {
      $entity['theme paths'][] = $entity['theme path'];
      unset($entity['theme path']);
   }
  }
}
```

So my template file is in custom_module/templates directory.

But after clearing cache always entity.tpl.php is used for all view modes.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using hook_process_HOOK($variables) for nodes view mode tpls :

```
function view_mode_tpl_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $vars['node']->type . '__' .$vars['view_mode'];
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thx, but Drupal provides template suggestion by view mode by default. I am asking about loading custom template from  a module.